# "for loop" does not find rows of a given condition

Tags: google-apps-script

The code for driver "1" summarize data, for driver "2" the code continue summarize data (data of 1 driver + data of 2 driver), but i need for each driver different results. What's the problem?

Thank you, for your time!

```
    function driverBort() {
      var srs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('List1');
      var col = srs.getRange('C:M').getValues();
      var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('IDs');
      var main = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Table');

      var type = data.getRange('A38').getValue();
      var tax =  data.getRange('D38').getValue();
      var drivers = main.getRange('A2:B10').getValues();

      var sum = 0;  


    for (var n = 0; n < col.length; n++) {
      for (var i = 0; i < drivers.length; i++) {
        if (col[n][0] == drivers[i][0]) {
          if (col[n][10] == type) {
            sum += col[n][7] * tax
            main.getRange(i+2,2).setValue(sum)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You should re-read the basics of GAS about how to get values in spreadsheets and re-write your code following the rules... I'm sure it will work better. Using the Logger will also help you to see what happens.

Comment: Yes for starters dont use setActiveSelection

Comment: @Serge insas I rewrote my code, but still doesn't work how i want it. New problems appear)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried your code but I think the issues is that you're using `.getValues` for a singe cell value, hence it is returning a 3D array. You then trying to compare a singular value to an array with this line `col[n][10] == type)` . Try changing your type and tax declaration lines to:

```
var type = data.getRange('A38').getValue();
var tax =  data.getRange('D38').getValue();
```

Note: `getValue` without the `s`.

Comment: Thank you for the note, but the mistake is somewhere in "Loop For".

Comment: @snoop31 vletech's answer is right (+1) what is exactly the error you have after changing your code following his advice?

Comment: @vletech:  small error, 2D is enough :-)  this is not the last 3D movie, just an array :-)

Comment: @Sergeinsas It's a bad habit I'm in of calling an array inside an array... I might start calling them an '[Inception Array](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/)' :)

Comment: He he... not a bad idea. :-)

Comment: @ Serge insas Script works, but counts wrong. For example, the first part takes driver "1" and counting rows according to the conditions in the second part. But for  driver "2" script continues to count rows and add to final data 1 driver.
1 - 120
2 - 300 (120  driver "1"  + 180 driver "2")
I need:
1 -120
2 - 180

Comment: @snoop31 I'm slightly confused. With the loops you've set up, it will do a complete iteration of the drivers array for each of the col array. For example (col[0]( drivers[0], drivers[1], drivers[2]), col[1]( drivers[0], drivers[1], drivers[2]), col[2]( etc...   If you want it to perform different you'll have to keep a count outside of the scope of the for loop.